# Remove items from menu SM Mega menu plugin

Tags: menu

Can someone please let me know how to remove the about us and contact links in my main menu, this is my store [vapersmoke.co.nz](https://vapersmoke.co.nz/)

I'm using the SM Mega Menu plugin and using the SM Jare theme from MagenTech, I've searched all over the admin panel and internet for info on this, but with no luck! Would it be coded in one of the css file?

Your help will be much appreciated

Peter

Comment: I think we would need a little insight into how your Menu items are built.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about a third party extension.

Answer (score 1):

Check they might have created a category to display this links....disable this category and you are done

Answer (score 0):

Most of the new themes are probiding to add custom link into the menu they have created static block to manage from admin

I would recommed you to check in

Admin panel => CMS => Click on Statick block

May be you can found there in one of the static block which could be similar name with Menu

Hope this will sure help you.